# how to position cities correctly on a world map??? geolocation markers for Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I recently discovered this awesome third party After Effects plugin called "Locations" It allows you to add geolocated markers to maps in After Effects.

Does anyone know if such a cartography plugin exists for Illustrator CC? I already googled and haven't found anything yet.

But it would be far better to be able to accurately position cities on a vector map in Illustrator prior to importing into After Effects.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you asking about the design aspect of the plugin that's used in After Effects or the ability to mark the actual location of a city on a vector map in illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question yo want to marker in a map with vectordata. You can use *ArcGIS* for this. Then make a *PDF* out of the map. Maps are produced this way can be too heavy, though.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. This site tries to build comprehensive answers not just few line conversational pieces. These should be reserved to comments. Try adding why you think the user wants to invest in using **ArcGIS** compared to other possible solutions. Note i also did some copy editing on your message. If you think it violates what you were saying feel free to edit or revert it back.

Answer (score 1):

There is a category of programs called Geograpgic Information Systems, GIS for short. These are CAD/Vector drawing packages that are designed to be suitable for mapmaking. They include a lot of features to deal with data import in form of latitude-longditude coordinates Other featires include well as projection transfornation of data. As such they would be perfect platforms to do this.

Instead of **ArcGIS** (suggested by Nicolas Tenorio), that is commercial. I suggest using [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/). Most GIS packages can export to DXF, PDF, (E)PS and even SVG. So getting the data out To illustrator is no problem.

It shouldnt take a unsurmountable effort to learn to use a GIS application if you know anything about CAD or Vector drawimg. Especially if you dont expect to learn all the intricasies of the app you should be up and running in a hour or so.

As an alternate strategy try to find a map that has your data. You can try something like open streetmap and delete the features you do not need. This might be a more conductive approach than trying to pin points in a possibly unknown projection.